# python dump __repr__ to stderr with clean linebreaks

Tags: python, apache

Was wondering if there's a way to dump instance's `__repr__` to stderr without all the Apache's log format junk ?

Currently this is the code

```
    def __repr__(self):
        # instance's repr of the object
        str = "<MyObj(\n"

        for col in db_fields:
            str += "%s = %s \n" % (col, self.get_db_col(col))

        str += ")> \n"

        return str

    # main script
    sys.stderr.write("%r", my_obj)
```

The log output is currently:

```
[Mon Feb 09 10:28:02 2015] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] <MyObj(, referer: https://some.domain.com/
[Mon Feb 09 10:28:02 2015] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] db_field_1 = 1 , referer: https://some.domain.com/
[Mon Feb 09 10:28:02 2015] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] db_field_2 = False , referer: https://some.domain.com/
[Mon Feb 09 10:28:02 2015] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] db_field_3 = 'Descr' , referer: https://some.domain.com/
[Mon Feb 09 10:28:02 2015] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] )>
```

It's impossible to read it, is there a way to trick it somehow without touching Apache's conf ?

The result that I wish to have is:

```
[Mon Feb 09 10:28:02 2015] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] <MyObj(, referer: https://some.domain.com/
db_field_1 = 1 , referer: https://some.domain.com/
db_field_2 = False , referer: https://some.domain.com/
db_field_3 = 'Descr' , referer: https://some.domain.com/
)>
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do about this *from Python's end*. This is Apache splitting your stderr output across line endings and prepending date, type and client IP address to each line. I don't think you can tell Apache not to do that from the process producing the stderr data.

Comment: Bummer, do you know where in Apache I can find it ?